# Libgit2sharp in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to run Libgit2Sharp in a Xamarin.iOS project (I'm currently running it on Xamarin.Droid).
For doing so, I was trying to follow the same approach than for Android (generating a custom native binaries package) but I have faced some doubts/problems.

First, iOS doesn't allow the use of dynamic libraries at least if you want to upload the app to the market.
Is there any "easy" way no rebuild libgit2sharp to make it run static libraries?
Probably the App will not go to the official App Store, but it would be nice to know if it is possible.

Another thing I have realized while checking the libgit2sharp source code is that iOS is not in the list of possible Operating Systems, so should I make any other modification to make it run on iOS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I found a way to run libgit2 in Xamarin.iOS.

Basically what I did was to generate the iOS libgit2 static libraries (you can use the Objective-git repository for doing so, as it is part of the process) and then modify LibGit2Sharp project to look for "__Internal" instead of the .dll/.so dynamic libraries.

The you just need to add the libgit2 static library to your Xamarin.iOS project, and that's all.

Hope someone finds this info helpful.